# Android and iOS preferences and unique identifier

Tags: android, ios, iphone, sharedpreferences, uniqueidentifier

I am planning on storing a unique identifier after a user logs in for the first time on an Android and Apple app.  This will make sure that the user can only access data from one device if they try to login through another device as I will flag then as having access.  I will save this unique identifier in the devices preferences and use it for requests to get this private data.

With that being said I know the preferences can be deleted or removed.  This piece of data isnt needed long term and in emergencies we can reset the users account back as if they never got access yet like for a factory reset or deleted app.

My question is, are there any issues with this?  These arent developers so somehow getting access to the user preferences to find that unique identifier and using it elsewhere shouldnt be an issue.

Comment: Why bother with a unique ID? Just use a standard login/password to your service and download the data for that user. This also means that if a user re-sets their device the unique ID will not be lost.

Comment: If I do that they can share their username/pw with anyone and get the same data.  This is tied per device, reason for the whole question.  I already mentioned that in emergencies they can request a reset, this is  temp event that isnt long term so if they reset it the event probably isnt in play anymore.

Comment: What happens if the device breaks and is replaced? Or the user buys a new phone? Or if they want to access the data from their phone on the move and their iPad at home? Or any scenario where the device changes? The user basically loses access to the content they've paid for.

Comment: Again I will repeat myself.  This is temp data.  If an event is 5 days long and they use the data for that long then after that they dont need it anymore.  If there phone somehow breaks during that time they can request an emergency reset.

Answer (score 0):

for IOS:

You shouldn't concern your self with that cause there is no need to store the identifiers to user prefs (and it is not a good practice).

You just use:
[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];

It will return the same value as long as it is called from the same device and same vendor. This is explained in:
http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/

Comment: I knew about that value and may use it.  What about Android though?  I need to create a unique ID in both places and storing that value in user preferences wouldnt be a big deal unless they delete the app, or cleared data, something they have no reason to do on this app.

Comment: as I know android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId() will also return the same value every time you call it so again no need for prefs

Comment: But I read that wont work on tablets or factory reset.  What could possible be the difference if they reset their phone for iOS and get a new vendor ID.  Same type of situation as if I created it myself.

Comment: I am not an Android expert but am certain that there has to be something you can rely on. If there is not, maybe there is some safer place you can store the identifier value. For example MAC has "key chain", I don't know if Android has something similar, but I think it does. But if you are not concerned about security than just store it in prefs.